# How do you understand the nature of curl?

Tags: curl

My teacher tells me the curl describes the component of rotation at a point in a vector field. When a ball is placed in a vector field with a non-zero curl, it tends to rotate.

Let's consider a field like $\{2 x y-\sin (x),x^2+e^{3 y}\}$.We can easily calculate the curl of this vector field is $0$. We can visualize this vector field by *Wolfram Mathematica* like follow:

```
StreamPlot[{2 x y - Sin[x], x^2 + E^(3 y)}, {x, -30, 30}, {y, -30, 30}]
```

[image]

But when I saw this vector field that I had visualized, I began to doubt my own understanding. Could it be that if I place a small ball on this red circle, the ball really won't spin? Or did my teacher lie to me?

[image]

Comment: Ummm... in which direction do you think the red ball would rotate?  (*Rotate*, not *Move*.)

Comment: With StreamPlot you lose information about the *length* of the vectors, so it's useless for thinking about the curl. For example, the plots of the vector fields $(1,0)$ and $(1+y^2,0)$ look identical (except for some length-based colouring with the new defaults in Mathematica 12), but they don't have the same curl; the first one is irrotational, the second one isn't.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Notice that those arrows flow from the east to the north. Then I think there must be a clockwise turning point on the inside of the bend and a counterclockwise turning point on the outside of the bend. Do you think it is reasonable for me to think so?

Comment: Can you imagine the ball changing directions without rotating? Supposedly that's what a zero-curl field would make it do.

Comment: @Karl Sorry, I can't imagine. I think the direction changed can only be because this little ball rotated.

Comment: You'll need to take into account the speed of the flow. If the flow on one side of the ball is faster than on the other side, it will cause the ball to rotate, even if the velocity vectors are parallel. Have a look at this 3b1b video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rB83DpBJQsE (the part about the curl starts at 4:32).

Comment: @HansLundmark  Note in [3:52s](https://youtu.be/rB83DpBJQsE?t=232) said, we usually use color present the length so that the line segments don't overlap, but not missing information as [you said above](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298745/how-do-you-understand-the-nature-of-curl#comment8952465_4298745).

Comment: In the video, all the vectors are drawn with (more or less) the same length, but the point is that the actual **flow** is **animated** so that you can see how fast it goes. Even if you colour the streamlines or the vector field, it's very hard to get a feeling for how little balls would rotate from a non-moving picture.

Comment: By the way, that's not what's said at 3:52. Did you mean to write some other timestamp?

Comment: @HansLundmark Oh, god. I first time to know the video in youtube is a omit version. I'm not sure if you can see the Chinese version of this video. It is in the [3:52s](https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV19s41157Z4?t=3m52s) in the Chinese full version

Comment: Ah, OK, then it makes more sense!

Comment: The fact that the flow goes from the east, then from the south is a *separate* issue from whether there is *curl* (and attendant rotation).  I see no *differential* in flow that would spin a ball in the red position.

Comment: @HansLundmark Note `VectorPlot[{1 + y^2, 0}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 VectorScaling -> Automatic]` is different with `VectorPlot[{1, 0}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, VectorScaling -> Automatic]`

Comment: Yes, of course. It's the results from **StreamPlot** that look the same (except for the colouring).